# How show smarty template from string in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, smarty, template-engine

I wanna use smarty template engine in yii2.
In my project, i need load view codes from database and render them from controller.

My question is this:

Is there any way to render a view code from string and control it like common render?

i need something like below:

```
$this->renderAsString($templateStr, ['param1'=>$val1, 'param2'=>$val2]);
```

this is important for me can access variable and function like as below code in `index.tpl` file.

```
$this->render('index.tpl'['param1'=>$val1, 'param2'=>$val2]);
```

I read this http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/resources.string.tpl but my answer is different, i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is special separate extension called [yii2-smarty](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-smarty) for rendering views with Smarty. You need to install it via Composer, then configure like this for usage:

```
return [
    //....
    'components' => [
        'view' => [
            'renderers' => [
                'tpl' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\smarty\ViewRenderer',
                    //'cachePath' => '@runtime/Smarty/cache',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

As for your specific problem, look at these two issues on Github:

- [Add ability to render view from string](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7309)
- [View renderer from db](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6252) - not implemented yet

Core developer Klimov Paul recommends to use `eval`, but also in Smarty dedicated function exists exactly for these kind of situations.

**Example 8.4. Another {eval} example**

> This outputs the server name (in uppercase) and IP. The assigned
>   variable `$str` could be from a database query.

```
<?php
$str = 'The server name is {$smarty.server.SERVER_NAME|upper} '
       .'at {$smarty.server.SERVER_ADDR}';
$smarty->assign('foo',$str);
?>
```

> Where the template is:

```
{eval var=$foo}
```